# How to fix the order of methods inside a test case generated by Randoop?

Tags: junit, randoop

I want to use Randoop to generate unit test cases for an application which consist of many API functions. I can specify which methods to use to form the tests using `methodlist` option. But what if this method uses the class fields which have to be set using some setter functions first. Right now, these setter functions are being called after the API call in almost all the tests generated by Randoop. Can I specify the order in which the methods are called in my test?

Answer (score 0):

Not currently.  I determined this by reading the [Randoop manual](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html).

If you want to suggest the feature, you can do so at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/randoop/randoop/issues) or on the [mailing list](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html#getting_help).